# How to copy parquet file from Azure Blob Storage into Snowflake table?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

To copy parquet file from Azure Blob Storage into Snowflake table, I have created a stored procedure, but I don't know how to convert timestamp in source data to date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_IMPORT_COPY_DATA(year varchar,month varchar,day varchar)
returns varchar
LANGUAGE sql
AS
  $$
  BEGIN
  let delete_query varchar:= 'delete from PRD_RAW_DATA.PUBLIC.SAMPLE_DATA where load_date = substr(to_char(CURRENT_DATE()),1,4) || substr(to_char(CURRENT_DATE()),6,2) || substr(to_char(CURRENT_DATE()),9,2)';
  execute immediate delete_query;
let uri varchar := concat(
'select 
$1:COMPANY_CODE,
$1:STORE_CODE,
$1:JAN_CODE,
$1:PERIOD,
$1:QUANTITY,
$1:AMOUNT,
$1:GROSS_PROFIT,
$1:SELLING_PRICE,
$1:SALE_QUANTITY,
$1:SALE_AMOUNT,
$1:SALE_GROSS_PROFIT,
$1:SALE_PRICE,
$1:NUMBER_OF_DEALERS,
$1:NUMBER_OF_VISITORS,
$1:LOAD_DATE
FROM @SYNAPSE_STAGE_PRD/delta/sample_data'
,'/year='
, :year
,'/month='
, :month
,'/day='
, :day
);
let copy_query varchar := concat('copy into PRD_RAW_DATA.PUBLIC.SAMPLE_DATA from '
                                        ,'('
                                        ,uri
                                        ,'(file_format => my_parquet_format, pattern => \'.*.parquet\') t'
                                        ,') force=TRUE'
                                    );
    execute immediate copy_query;
    return(copy_query);
  END;
  $$;
```

This is error message;
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 77 at position 4 : Failed to cast variant value "2022-08-17 00:00:00.000" to DATE

Do you know the solution to this?
Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a timestamp to date if needed, like this:

```
select '2022-08-17 00:00:00.000'::date;
```

gives me:

```
2022-08-17
```

In your case I am not sure which is the column that gives that error but if I would take one that looks like a timestamp:

```
$1:LOAD_DATE
```

you could do:

```
$1:LOAD_DATE::date
```

Comment: I tried "$1:LOAD_DATE::date", but the same error occurred.

Comment: What about trying **as_date($1:LOAD_DATE)**

Comment: A different error has occurred. "Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 36 at position 4 : SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected 'as'.
syntax error line 5 at position 18 unexpected ','."

Comment: Can you try the SELECT statement directly on Snowflake UI? Does it work using casting as **::date** or the function **as_date**?

Comment: Use `TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP($1:LOAD_DATE))`, it has worked well. Thank you for your support.